# C/C++, truncating a small float number to 2 meaningful digits and expressing it in a scientific way

Tags: c++, truncation

I got some small float numbers which should be appended to file names. These files then will be displayed in a monitoring website. This way, people can get a brief impression of a experimental run solely by its filename. 
A typical small number(the value of vacuum pressure) is :

```
1.2528168904794602e-07.
```

In C/C++, I hope it can be truncated to a scientific number like

```
1.3e-07
```

This 1.3e-07 will be a part of a file name.

I'm not trying to print the value on a screen. As a result, using the following iostream command might not be a option.

```
std::cout.precision(2);
```

Any suggestions ? Thanks !

Comment: If you're not displaying the value, what are you doing with it? Showing significant digits and scientific formatting is only used when actually displaying the values, and have no meaning in just storing the values.

Comment: well, I think std::io has a flag for that (`setiosflags(ios::scientific)` ) combined with precision that would work. Anyway, you can also stream "into a string" for storing that value as part of a filename

Comment: You can zero appropriate bits of the binary representation of the value. Seems to be a bad idea, but it should work perfectly as floating-point types follow the IEEE754 standard :)

Answer (score 2):

Use a combination of `precision` and `setf`:

This does what you want:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){

  double pressure = 1.2528168904794602e-07;
  cout.setf(ios::scientific);
  cout.precision(1);
  cout << "pressure: " << pressure << endl;
}
```

If you're writing to a file, you can still use `precision`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
  double pressure = 1.2528168904794602e-07;
  ofstream fout("out.txt");
  fout.setf(ios::scientific);
  fout.precision(1);
  fout << "pressure: " << pressure << endl;
  fout.close();
}
```

Here's an example of using the value to write an output file with the value as part of the filename (using a `stringstream` to create the filename):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
  double pressure = 1.2528168904794602e-07;
  ostringstream sout;
  sout.precision(1);
  sout.setf(ios::scientific);
  sout << "Prefix" << pressure << ".txt";
  ofstream fout(sout.str().c_str());
  fout << "Writing to outfile" << endl;
  fout.close();
}
```

The above code creates a file named `Prefix1.3e-07.txt`

What might you be doing with the value where we can't use `precision`?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all of posts!
I actually figured out by searching.

Here is my solution :

```
...
string new_file_name;
stringstream ss (stringstream::in | stringstream::out);
ss << std::setprecision(1) << std::scientific << pressure_value ;
string stest = ss.str();
new_file_name += stest ;
...
```

It's not exactly same as my script, but it's equivalent.

Comment: By searching and not referencing my conveniently placed answer ;-)? You don't need to put `ss.str()` in a new variable, you can just say `new_file_name += ss.str()`

Comment: @AndyG, sorry for you feeling like that. The thing is I didn't and can't just wait a solution here, right ? In parallel, I tried to figure out by myself. The reason of my assigning `ss.str()` to `stest` is I need a string type to handle `ss` temporarily. Because `new_file_name` is not a string type, is "TString" type(defined in an OO environment - ROOT under which my scripts running) which is almost same as string but not exactly. For instance, `new_file_name +=ss.str()` doesn't work because "TString" type hasn't a function of `str()` while string has.

Comment: No worries, seriously, that was tongue in cheek of me. Please don't keep my answer as the accepted one unless it solved your problem for you. Thanks for the clarification.